# ASP.NET DetailsVew rebind the dropdownlist after insert items

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET and have been trying to make the dropdownlist works correctly in DetailsView, but no luck so far.  I am getting every close to accomplish this, so much appreciated of someone can help me out here.

An error that I am getting is:

> Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be
>   used in the context of a databound control.

I have this code in my DetailsView:

```
<EditItemTemplate>  
    <asp:DropDownList id="VendorName" 
        datasourceid="VendorSqlDataSource" 
        AutoPostBack="true" 
        datatextfield="VendorName" 
        DataValueField="VendorID"    
        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("VendorID") %>'   
        runat="server" 
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged" /> 

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="VendorSqlDataSource" 
        ConnectionString="<%$Connectionstrings:ConnectionString%>"  
        SelectCommand="SELECT VendorID, VendorName from MDF_Vendor" 
        runat="server">  
    </asp:SqlDataSource>  
</EditItemTemplate>  


<EditItemTemplate> 
    <asp:DropDownList id="VendorBUName" 
        datasourceid="VendorBUSqlDataSource"  
        datatextfield="VendorBUName" 
        DataValueField="VendorBUID"    
        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("VendorBUID") %>'   
        runat="server"/> 

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="VendorBUSqlDataSource" 
        runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$Connectionstrings:ConnectionString%>" 
        selectcommand="SELECT VendorBUID, VendorBUName 
                       from MDF_VendorBU 
                       Where VendorID = @VendorID" 
        <SelectParameters>  
            <asp:Parameter Name="VendorID" Type="Int32" />  
        </SelectParameters>  
    </asp:SqlDataSource>  
</EditItemTemplate>
```

In my code behind list, I have this code to rebuild the list of VendorBUName dropdownlist when VendorName selected.

```
protected void ddlVendor_SelectedIndexChanged
               (object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DropDownList ddlVendor =
        (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("VendorName");
    DropDownList ddlVendorBU =
        (DropDownList)DetailsView1.FindControl("VendorBUName");


    if (ddlVendorBU != null)
    {
        Response.Write("SelectChanged");
        int VendorID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlVendor.SelectedValue.ToString());
        Response.Write("VendorID: " + VendorID);

        ddlVendorBU.Items.Clear();

        string strConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT VendorBUID, VendorBUName FROM dbo.MDF_VendorBU WHERE VendorID = @VendorID";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VendorID", VendorID);
        DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        dAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        con.Open();
        dAdapter.Fill(objDs);

        con.Close();


        if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in objDs.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                ddlVendorBU.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem( (dr["VendorBUName"]).ToString(), "-1") );
            }
            ddlVendorBU.DataBind();  //<-- Problem HERE can not rebind it.
        }

    }
}
```

This is working so far in DetailsView.  I click Edit, these 2 dropdownlists selected the correct value.  When I select another Vendor in VendorName ddl, it refreshes the VendorBUName list.  Great! However, when I try to ddlVendorBU.DataBind(); to rebind the VendorBUName list, it gives the error above.  If removed that, it won't update the record for VendorBUName because is not bound to the field.

I am totally stuck, if someone can please help.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use  ddlVendorBU.DataBind(); you must define DataSource property.

If you wish insert Item, you don't need DataBind method.

So

You can try this code without DataBind

```
foreach (DataRow dr in objDs.Tables[0].Rows)
{
     ddlVendorBU.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem( (dr["VendorBUName"]).ToString(), "-1") );
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did that in my code as you can see, but it will not save the VendorBUID when I update record, because it is not bind, correct?

Comment: you can delete DataBind when you add items with : Control.Items.Add

Comment: I'am happy to help you , foreach (DataRow dr in objDs.Tables[0].Rows)
{
     ddlVendorBU.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem( (dr["VendorBUName"]).ToString(), "-1") );
}
 just this without DataBind()

Comment: I'am happy to help you Milacay

Answer (score 1):

By chance are you doing any sort of bind on your page load? and if so are you checking if it is a postback?  Your page load is going to fire before your selection change event and if it rebound something there you're not working with the same data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do without your `Bind("VendorBUID")` and set the SelectedValue property programmatically?  I think that's what's causing your problem.

Now, rebinding your ddlVendorBU is also going to wipe out anything you manually added, because that's what binding does.  So you might also want to set the `DataSource` property before rebinding, to create the DDL with the proper items.

Also, since you want your ddlVendorBU to have a meaningful `SelectedValue` property (or so I infer) you shouldn't use -1 as your value parameter in every trip through the loop when added items.  Use the BUID field.

ETA: code:

```
if (objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) 
{
   ddlVendorBU.DataSource = objDs.Tables[0];
   ddlVendorBU.DataTextField = "VendorBUName";
   ddlVendorBU.DataValueField = "VendorBUID";
   ddlVendorBU.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I did try that also, but getting error 'CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList' does not contain a definition for 'ItemTextField' and no extension method 'ItemTextField' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry about that - I did it from memory.  It's `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` for the property names.